# Reload CollectionView with Scrolling (Gesture)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

[image]I worked on **UICollectionView** and I don't solve some problem. Is there any way to reload UICollectionView with scrolling - gesture on it.

When I scroll the right side or left side , I want to change the active week and refresh collectionview (day's hours events)."The Calendar is JTAppleCalendar"

I search some articles but i didnt get any answer. Some of them use the **PanGestureRecogniser** but i dont implement it also i dont know this is the correct way. Plase share your power

Comment: Can you show your design?

Comment: Do you need to show the collection view again when scrolling down?

Comment: Have you tried by disabling isScrollEnabled property of collectionView

Comment: I added a picture and i try to explain my problem

Comment: use scrollviewDelegate and you have to call scrollViewDidScroll method to see and calculate the scrolled area, depending on that you have to move collection view to specific index path.

Comment: can you share some code or link please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly Add the collectionView Scrolling direction to Vertical either programmatically in ViewDidLoad or in Interface Builder,& add swipe Right and Left gesture to perform action like reload data when swipe.

```
    let layout = self.CollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.vertical


func perfromGesture(){

    let leftGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleSwipes(sender:)))
    let rightGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleSwipes(sender:)))

    leftGesture.direction = .left
    rightGesture.direction = .right

    self.CollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(leftGesture)
    self.CollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(rightGesture)
}


@objc func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    if (sender.direction == .left) {
        print("left")
        //Perform Action
    }

    if (sender.direction == .right) {
        print("right")
        //Perform Action
    }
 }
```

Comment: If i do this , I dont see the days hours. I reach the hours with scrolling up and down

Comment: U want to scroll up and down , with swipe left and right??

Comment: I want to reload CollectionView data with swipe right and left. Also i want to give an action to swipe

Comment: You are perfect. It works properly. But i want to ask a question . Can I do this swipe action with more distance not suddenly.